# Pass user defined table from SQL to C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to call a external c# method from SQL. The parameter that I am passing is a user defined table. Most information that I found was from C# to SQL, but not vice versa.

Comment: Usually, you won't want your SQL Server behaving as an Application Server.  Wisdom would judge what you should and shouldn't do in an CLR proc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you CAN do this with `CLR Stored Procedures` see:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/19/sql-server-introduction-to-clr-simple-example-of-clr-stored-procedure/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx

But I would be extremely wary of why you need to put this in place.

SQL Server is awesome as a stable platform to store application data that respects referential integrity. It has features such as above, but I would argue they really shouldn't be used unless totally necessary. Having used `CLR Stored Procedures` in the past, they can add a fair amount of complication and general maintenance overhead to your project. It is pretty far outside of best practice to do this.